# Writing data to a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, html

Reading a value of a JSON is possible .. Likewise,Can we write the textbox values to a JSON variable when we click submit button

Example:`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Sample Employee Details
</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="emp_json.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<p>Emp ID:<input type="text" id="empid" /></p>
<p>Name:<input type="text" id="name" /></p>
<p>Mobile:<input type="text" id="mob" /></p>
<p><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add();"/></p>
</form>
<script>
function add()
{
    EmployeeDetails.EmployeeID = document.getElementById('empid').value;
    EmployeeDetails.Name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    EmployeeDetails.Mobile = document.getElementById('mob').value;alert("hi");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

MY JSON:

```
var EmployeeDetails = new Array();

EmployeeDetails = [
                    {
                    "EmployeeID":"",
                    "Name":"",
                    "Mobile":""
                    }
                ];
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing JavaScript objects with JSON.

Comment: Yup i am confused so i have posted this

Comment: please Refer to this question, you definately get help --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery--

Comment: Where do you want to send the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to use [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) from the jQuery library.